# Iphone dismissModalViewController animation

Tags: iphone, presentmodalviewcontroller, dismiss

How can I modify the animation for dismiss?

for present, I've used :

```
SlideShow *slider = [[SlideShow alloc] initWithNibName:@"SlideShow" bundle:nil];
slider.view.alpha = 0.0;
[self presentModalViewController: slider animated: NO];

[UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];

slider.view.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

and it works..

But how about a way to dismiss it using a custom animation (I was looking for a Fade-Out animation for dismiss)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fading view controllers the old school way, since iOS 3 the easiest and best way to fade a view controller is to set its property: (ex. in the init method)

```
self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
```

Your view controller will then fade nicely in and out.

Comment: Thanks,that's what I wound up using right after I've posted the question but this still doesn't answer my question. How can I perform a custom animation?!  (I'd linke to know a general solution for this)

Answer (score 1):

`presentModalViewController` is essentially a method that serves up a pre-baked animation for your `viewController.view`. If you want to make a custom animation for dismissing or presenting a modal view, you have to handle it all on your own.